# Почему переменные получают разные значения?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#define f(x) (1.0f/(1.0f+exp(-x)))
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b[2], c,d;
    b[0] = 0.5;
    b[1] = 0.3;
    a = b[0] + b[1];
    c = f(a);
    d = f(b[0] + b[1]);
    cout << c << " " << d << endl;
}
```

c=0.689974 d=0.549834
Почему переменные c и d принимают разные значения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define f(x) (1.0f/(1.0f+exp(-x)))
```

При передаче суммы выражение примет вид:

```
1.0f/(1.0f+exp(-0.5 + 0.3))
```

Т.е. вы вычисляете `f(0.2)`
Вы можете обернуть сумму в скобки: `f((b[0] + b[1]))` или же обернуть `x` в дефайне `#define f(x) (1.0f/(1.0f+exp(-(x))))`, но это такое себе занятие.
Чтобы не было подобных ситуаций задавайте функцию явно:

```
float f(float x){
    return 1.f / (1.f + exp(-x));
}
```